# Error while import IPython.HTML in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTML' from 'IPython' (C:\Users\sriva\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should import html like this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
```

Comment: Yeah, it works now, thanks.